# Using a browning dish to microwave meat

Tags: enzymatic-browning

In general:

Would the meat need to be covered while cooking, and if so with what? (There's no cover for my dish, and I assume plastic wrap would melt).

How much time would the extra heat reduce the cooking time... maybe 20%?

Specifically:

Would it be appropriate to cook frozen (thawed) cod on a microwave browning dish? I'm not sure if or when fish should be browned.

For raw chicken thighs on a microwave browning dish; any tips to get the skin as browned or crispy-ish as possible?

Comment: If you want your meat to have a good texture don't use a microwave. All the gadgets in the world won't keep it from getting rubbery.

Comment: A microwave is all I can use right now; I've cooked meat in it many times, and it has NEVER been rubbery. Do you not know if cod should be browned or not, or how to best brown a chicken skin on a hot surface?

Comment: I don't think its possible for chicken thighs to get a seared skin in the microwave. As far as cod goes, you can brown it if you want. However, I strongly recommend using a pan, not a microwave.

Comment: Browning starts happening at 300º; the browner heats up to over 400º... why would that not brown chicken skin?